# Ansible: run certain yaml tasks file for all hosts

Tags: ansible

I try to run certain yaml tasks file for all hosts, as follows (main.yml):

```
- name: prepare nodes
  include_tasks: node.yml node="{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

node.yml:

```
- block:
    - name: Task 1...

    ...

    - name: Task 100...

  delegate_to: "{{ node }}"
```

However I get this error: `Invalid options for include_tasks: node`. I think it used to work in this manner. Anyway I tried to move `loop` from main.yml into node.yml (right after `delegate_to`). I also tried to skip `node="{{ item }}"` part. But I always get errors.

What is the proper way to apply a task file to several hosts within a role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you put your `node` variable under `vars` then loop.

```
- name: include tasks
  include_tasks: node.yml
  vars:
    node: '{{ item }}'
  loop: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

Above code is working.

Comment: I would not do that. If somebody else uses your role, that person will not expect that it runs on more hosts than they actually intended it to. It can lead to confusion and errors later.

Comment: @toydarian: good point. I'll mention this fact in the role description. In this particular case it's a "monitoring" role that is supposed to monitor all available nodes. In a general case you are correct though.

Answer (score 1):

A play runs on the hosts you specified. You can run certain tasks on a subset of nodes using `when`.

But you can have multiple plays in a playbook. So you need to specify a play with `hosts: all` where you run the tasks you want to run everywhere and another one which runs the rest of the tasks.
Your playbook could look like this:

```yaml
---
# This is a play
- name: run on all
  hosts: all
  vars:
    somevar: 'test'
  tasks:
    - name: prepare nodes
      include_tasks: node.yml

# This is another play
- name: run on group
  hosts: hostgroup
  vars:
    somevar: 'example'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 'This runs on all hosts in hostgroup'

# Both plays are in the same playbook
```

Comment: thank you! I need this include to be a part of certain role and not a separate play... that's why I have a main.yml and node.yml...